# Type conversion in C++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I want to store few animals in a vector. Animals may be Cats or Dogs. Later I want cats and dogs back from the vector. Can I use type casting here?

eg.

```
class Animal{

string name;

void makeSound();

}

class Dog:public Animal{

string owner;

void makeSound(){

cout << "Woof";

}

class Cat:public Animal{

string home;

void makeSound(){

cout << "Mew";

}
```

in main program.

```
vector<Animal> list;

Cat c = Cat();

list.push_back(c);

Cat cat = (Cat)list.at(0);   // how can I do this
```

PS:

This is not the exact code with syntax. But I need to do something like this.

Comment: You really don't need anything like this. If you want cats and dogs, make a vector of cats and a vector of dogs.

Comment: You have slicing issue with `vector<Animal>`.

Comment: Jarod42, I like the image of an Animal slicing issue! Don't tell PETA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store pointer to Animal in your vector like:-

```
std::vector<Animal*> vec;
```

There should be no need to explicitly check which type of object you are storing in vector...After all that's the essence of virtual functions in C++.

Anyway if you want it then :-

```
void func( Animal* ptr )
{
   if ( Cat* cat = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(ptr) )
      //cat type
   if ( Dog* dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*> (ptr) )
      //dog type
}
```

Comment: I googled and consulted few friends.
This is the answer I needed.
Always use pointers when you need to do things like this was an advice.
:)